# Sending a WhatsApp message to several contacts through URL

Tags: url, whatsapp

I know that one can send a WhatsApp message to a specific contact using a URL. For example, if the phone number of the person I want to send a message is +573001234567 I would use

https://wa.me/573001234567?text=hello

But, is there a way to send the same message to more than one contact using only one URL? Something like
[https://wa.me/573001234567,573001111111?text=hello](https://wa.me/573001234567?text=hello)
or so?

Answer (score 3):

NO. There is no support such like that.

If you want to leverage whatsapp APIs to send the messages to multiple user at once you can use [Twilio whatsapp APIs](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp)